# How to invert 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' transforms behaviour in blender Python

Tags: python, scripting, transforms

I've made an Addon that allows Users to **handle Uvs directly from the 3D viewport** by **overriding the context**.
Everything works well except thaht when you run default scale, rotate or move **everything seems to be inverted**, wich is a normal behaviour because when you increase the scale of a face it decreases the size of the texture projected on it.

Same thing for moving: if you move the face to the right, texture moves to the left and so one.

So here is my request:
is there any means to tell Blender:

When Running this modal:

if: bpy.ops.transform.resize('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

bpy.ops.transform.resize(invert_'INVOKE_DEFAULT')

thanks for your answer.

Bests

Comment: The `INVOKE_DEFAULT` parameter has nothing to do with the actual values that are processed by the operator, it only tells the operator whether or not it should present you with a popup panel before executing itself, or whether it should wait for your input before executing. As suggested you can try creating a new modal operator, plug in the mouse event and feed the opposite values to an override of the operator

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i wanted to know if there was a mean to simply invert  move, scale and rotate without recoding this three items. It seems there is no alternative way to do it. Bests